# Custom jQuery Selector That Returns Selected Element Properties Like LINQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, performance, css-selectors

### The Problem

I need some properties of each item that query returns as array of objects

What we do right now

> $('*selector*').each(*create array of texts or whatsoever*);

### What is wrong?

> Why should we iterate over elements for each requirement?

Here is the same thing in LINQ

```
IQueryable<Book>;
books.Select(b=> b.Text).ToArray();
// or another sample
books.Select(b=> new { b.Text , b.ISBN}).ToArray();
```

### What do we/i need?

Selecting specified element properties as array of objects without reiterating over elements - something that called ***deferred enumeration***

### Is it possible?

I think yes it is, because right now i have some ideas.

*`I already know about 'map' and 'each' methods, beware that both of them will reiterate over selector items.So yes map will results what i want, but not exactly.
Also note that even C# that have more better performance than java-script is using this method that i'm asking for,
So this is a requirement for all web-developers not just me and that's exactly why i'm sharing the problem here to be solved.`*

### Research result

Iteration over elements using jQuery is inevitable because jQuery itself is not finding elements using loop over document elements until that's necessary for example pseudo classes, so for implementing deferred enumeration over jQuery infrastructure we have to force jQuery to iterate over items, and that makes it slow.

I'd implemented deferred enumeration using a pseudo class named 'select' and passing in .net like lambda expression.That was handling selects very nicely just like .net, but result was slower than map and each jQuery methods up to 50%.Finally the answer is jQuery map method.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible without iteration in jQuery? Or are you telling us that it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var books_text = $(".book").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

var books_info = $(".book").map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
        text: $this.text(),
        isbn: $this.attr("isbn")  // If stored in an attribute.
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: thanks for fast response, but map is reiterating over elements again, and not just on elements. it is two for loop inside each other , one for elements and one for each key on object.

Comment: @Beygi, I'm afraid I don't understand, do you mean `map()` iterates *twice* over the elements? Also, by `each key on object`, do you mean each attribute of the element?

Comment: No, I'm not, if you look at line 756 of jquery 1.6.1 you can see that it's iterating over each key of elements, and because we have more than one elements the result would be..., and also it has been commented : Go through every key on the object

Comment: And also remember we want to do this without another loop, because if we do $.each will do the same.

Comment: @Beygi, line 756 is in [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), which is not the same thing as the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method I use in my answer (the one I use applies to jQuery objects, `$.map()` is a completely different method exposed by the `$` object itself).

Comment: Also, keep in mind `map()` is like an `each()` that accumulates its results in an array. That seems to be what you're asking for, but maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about $.map, I'm sorry. but is it loop-less?

Comment: @Beygi, well, that depends on your stance on looping versus mapping. I'd say it's exactly as loopless as the `Select()` calls in your question :)

Comment: before i say any thing else let me thank you, it's so nice of you to helping me, but i think that i have to edit question that the select is executing over an IQueryable object.

Comment: @Beygi, *IQueryable*? Now that's interesting, but it's not what your question says. I'd suggest you at least change the title to `Implement IQueryable in Javascript with jQuery`, so your intent is clear and other interested people can help.

Comment: but i think that i said without reiterating over elements, which means with one loop that currently is iterating by jQuery selector itself.

Comment: I'm still curious about the $.map you just said, i have to check jQuery source code, unless you know that it has another loop inside.

Comment: @Beygi, if I understand you correctly, you think that in LINQ, multiple calls to `Select()` against an `IQueryable` are only iterating over that `IQueryable` once?

Comment: Okay, so what exactly do you mean by `one loop that currently is iterating by jQuery selector itself`? :)

Comment: it's simple like this $('elements:get-value') i have values as array without reiterating over elements for value of elements.

Comment: So why didn't you mention that you want help with a custom caching selector in your question?

Comment: Perhaps Beygi is looking for a deferred enumeration mechanism? If we use javascript to map an array into a new array with the goal to do something with the elements in the new array, we would have to iterate over the elements twice, once for mapping and once for doing that something. Having a deferred enumeration mechanism we would only have to iterate once - the mapping function would be invoked on each element as they are visited. This is easily accomplished in C#. Don't know the best way to do it in javascript though...

Comment: actually I'd searched for it before asking. i didn't find anything maybe after 5 years working as a web developer i still don't know how to search or something.because i thought that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MårtenWikström well done...well done, sorry i knew the deferred enumeration thing, maybe i confused because of 03:00 AM time.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you a lot, for what you did, actually $.map could be the answer, but not exactly.maybe you know me by my reputation score.

Comment: for those people who might get confused about $.map and $('selector').map, because of these comments.They should know that $(selector).map will call the same $.map inside and passing it to pushStack.